# If $2x+3y \propto \sqrt{xy}$ ,then prove that $9x^2+4y^2 \propto xy$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on the following problem which one of my friends gave me:

> If $2x+3y \propto \sqrt{xy}$ ,then prove that $9x^2+4y^2 \propto xy$.

The problem could have been easier if I had to prove $4x^2+9y^2 \propto xy$ but this problem has stumped me.

Can someone please help ? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: When you write proportional what do you mean? I guess by $f\propto g$ you mean $f=kg$ with $k$ a natural number? Or not?

Comment: @hamedp  yes ,you are right.. $f \propto g \implies f=kg.$

Comment: Are you sure that this is true?

Comment: I too have  confusion about the veracity of the problem and I told my friend. But he insists that the problem is true even though there is every chance that the problem might be wrong.

Comment: I fleshed out my answer a little to show that $x$,$y = 0$ is the only solution pair that could satisfy your equations (so the result is not true in general).

Comment: Looks like the problem is wrong. Should be either $3x+2y$ or $4x^2+9y^2$. What a pain!

Comment: @martycohen even then, remember that $(3x + 2y)^2 \neq 9x^2 + 4y^2$, and the same logic follows for your other case in reverse

Comment: But the difference is 12xy which *is* proportional to xy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{A) }2x+3y \propto \sqrt{xy}\qquad \text{B) }9x^2+4y^2 \propto xy$$
From A we get
$$4 x^2+12 x y+9 y^2 \propto xy$$
Combining A and B we get
$$4 x^2+12 x y+9 y^2 = k(9x^2+4y^2)$$
$$\Rightarrow 4 x^2+12 x y+9 y^2 = 9kx^2+4ky^2$$
From this we see that no $k$ will give an $xy$ term, so the statement is false. If we continue, we get
$$ 12xy = x^2(9k-4)+y^2(4k-9)$$
$$ xy = c_1x^2+c_2y^2$$
This is even more nonsensical. Further, if we substitute in the definition of $k$ from A we get
$$4 x^2+12 x y+9 y^2 = \frac{2x+3y}{\sqrt{xy}}(9x^2+4y^2)$$
Solving this for $y$, we get
$$y = \frac{-2x}{3}$$
Since the signs of $x$ and $y$ differ for all non-zero $x$,$y$ we conclude that the original statement only holds for $x$,$y = 0$, and does not hold in general

Comment: Thanks you so much for the detailed clarification. I am going to accept the answer but I think there is a typo :   " If we continue, we get
$$ xy = x^2(9k-4)+y^2(4k-9)"$$...should be replaced by  " If we continue, we get
$$ 12xy = x^2(9k-4)+y^2(4k-9)"$$.

Comment: @learner You are absolutely correct. That mistake is a result of that being the place where I originally split off and took my answer down another path with different constants, but I forgot to fix this when I chose the provided solution. Good catch... I'll fix this right away! Edit: I have edited my answer. Glad I could help!